# Validation check on Mobile number in C# and JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, validation

I am trying to do a validation check on mobile number from both C# code and Javascript.

Following should be validated OK:

- Length equal to 5 or 8+
- Can start with +XXxxxx
- Can start with 00xxxxxxx

I tried using:

C# code:

```
@"(^((([0-9]{5})|((\+[0-9]{2})[0-9]+)|((00[0-9]{2})[0-9]+))|((([0-9]{8,})|((\+[0-9]{2})[0-9]+)|((00[0-9]{2})[0-9]+))))$)"
```

JavaScript:

```
/^((([0-9]{5})|(((00[0-9]{2})|(\+?[0-9]{2}))[0-9]+))|(([0-9]{8})|(((00[0-9]{2})|(\+?[0-9]{2}))[0-9]+)))$/
```

With these expressions I am able to validate for 1st and last requirement but not the 2nd one (+XXxxxx).

Please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

use the OR option in the regular expression

Sample:

```
(\+XX)|(00)
```